# Dagger2 - Insert value in @Module without using constructor

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Following CodingInFlow's video tutorials on Dagger, I've reached the point where I'm seeing the use of @BindsInstance inside a @Component.Builder.

Having the following classes:

Model class:

```java
public class DieselEngine implements Engine {
    private static final String TAG = "Car";

    private int horsePower;

    @Inject
    public DieselEngine(int horsePower) {
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Diesel engine started. Horsepower = " + horsePower);
    }
}
```

the Modules:

```java
@Module
public class DieselEngineModule {

    private int horsePower;
//
//    public DieselEngineModule() {
//
//    }
//
//    @Provides
//    int provideHorsePower(@Named("dieselParam") int horsePower) {
//        return horsePower;
//    }

    public DieselEngineModule(int horsePower) {
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
    }

    @Provides
    int provideHorsePower(int horsePower) {
        return horsePower;
    }

//    We no longer need to manually instantiate DieselEngine obj using "new DieselEngine(horsePower)".
//    Because we created a "provideHorsePower()" method, and we @Inject-ed the constructor of
//    DieselEngine "DieselEngine(int horsePower){..}" so that the provideHorsePower() can inject into it.
    @Provides
    Engine provideEngine(DieselEngine dieselEngine) {
        return dieselEngine;
    }
}
```

```java
public abstract class PetrolEngineModule {

//    @Provides
//    Engine provideEngine(PetrolEngine engine) {
//        return engine;
//    }

    @Binds
    abstract Engine bindEngine(PetrolEngine engine);

    // NOTE: abstract methods are never instantiated, so we can't use normal @Provides methods, only static @Provides methods


}
```

the Component:

```java
@Component(modules = {
        WheelsModule.class,
        DieselEngineModule.class,
        })
public interface CarComponent {

    Car getCar();

//    Dagger 2 does not inject fields automatically. It can also not inject private fields.
//    If you want to use field injection you have to define a method in your @Component interface
//    which takes the instance into which you would like Dagger 2 to inject an object into this field.
//    ex: all fields with @Inject from MainActivity will be injected once this method is used.
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder horsePower(@Named("horse power") int horsePower);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder engineCapacity(@Named("engine capacity")int engineCapacity);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder moduleParam(@Named("dieselParam")int someNumber);

//        Builder dieselEngineModule(DieselEngineModule dem);

        // dagger will automaticaly implement this method, we just have to declare it, because
        // we are overwriting the builder definition
        CarComponent build();

    }

}
```

My question is: is there any way to "inject" a variable inside the PetrolEngineModule, in order to store it there, without having to add a parameter to the constructor of the module (see the commented method in the component) ?

for example: `int a;` inside PetrolEngineModule, which would be injected by the @Named("dieselParam") integer from the component. So that it would be set only once, when the Module is created for the first time.

I've experimented with the commented method in the DieselEngineModule, where the @Named variable is directly provided from the Component, in order to be used when providing the DieselEngine. But is that okay? I could use some advice here. Is that what I want to do? Use the @Named variable from the Component/Dependency Graph instead of storing it in the Module?

Comment: There's no need to inject anything in a Module. All the provision methods can access bound classes as parameters, hence you can just add your param as a parameter for the function returning DieselEngine

Comment: I've found the definition of provision method (https://dagger.dev/api/2.11/dagger/Component.html) but I'm not entirely sure which ones you mean, or which classes you refer to by "bound classes". Sorry, but could you please clarify?

Comment: "provision method" = a method annotated with @Provides

If you have a binding for an integer annotated with `@Named("dieselParam")` you can just write ` @Provides
    Engine provideEngine(@Named("dieselParam") a) {
        return new DieselEngine(horsePower);
    }`

Though I'm a bit confused by your question, you say you've tried this, and that's ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried that. What I'm asking is if there any way to "send" 2 @Named integer parameters to the module, and have that module provide one of the integers(explicitly chosen by me) to the provideEngine method, without using ```return new DieselEngine(dieselEngine);```

Comment: I know I can just use @Named("dieselParam") inside the DieselEngine class directly, but I'm asking if I can have more than 1 field with the same object type (integer, for example) in my module, and provide one of them to a class without explicitly calling it through the class constructor.
Or would that be bad practice, or not necessary?

Comment: I'm confused as what you're trying to achieve. You can have 2 different integers as long as they have 2 different annotations. Wrt storing values in Modules, there's never any reason to do that, you usually have module with fields when those are passed as parameters to the constructors. If you want to provide one of 2 options when constructing a class you need a way to decide how.   You might bind an enum/boolean and depending on that value then in the `@Provides` function you decide what to pass to DieselEngine constructor

Comment: This clarifies my question, I think. So in case I had a Module with multiple values  stored in it, some of which are the same type, the best approach (and only one?) would be to pass them at the constructor. Is this correct?
Thank you very much for the help!